# Optional in Swift, return count of array

Tags: swift

Help me with Optional hell in Swift. How to return count of array for key "R". `self.jsonObj` can be null

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return (self.jsonObj["R"]! as? NSArray)?.count;
}
```

Comment: Swift language should be easy, isn't it?

Comment: Should be, unless if I learn it good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take this a step at a time.

`self.jsonObj` may be `nil` so you need to treat it as an Optional:

`self.jsonObj?["R"]`

This will either return 1) `nil` if `self.jsonObj` is `nil` or if "R" is not a valid key or if the value associated with "R" is `nil` 2) an Optional wrapped object of some type.  In other words, you have an Optional of some unknown type.

The next step is to find out if it is an `NSArray`:

`(self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)`

This will return an Optional of type `NSArray?` which could be `nil` for the above reasons or `nil` because the object in `self.jsonObj` was some other object type.

So now that you have an Optional NSArray, unwrap it if you can and call `count`:

`(self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)?.count`

This will call count if there is an `NSArray` or return nil for the above reasons.  In other words, now you have an `Int?`

Finally you can use the **nil coalescing operator** to return the value or zero if you have `nil` at this point:

`(self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)?.count ?? 0`

Comment: Good answer, but also a really good example of why you should parse your JSON down to real Swift data types rather than storing it as `[String:AnyObject]`. Constantly checking that your elements are the type you expect is cumbersome and error-prone. Do it once when the data shows up.

Comment: why this doesn't work? `NSLog("%@", (self.jsonObj?["R"]! as? NSArray)?)`

Comment: Also `(self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)?[0].count + (self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)?[1].count ?? 0` fails to compile

Comment: That doesn't work because the last `?` doesn't unwrap the optional value and you can't pass the optional to `NSLog`. If you know for sure the `NSArray` is there, you can use `!` to force the unwrap. If it is `nil` you will crash.  If you are not sure, then use the nil coalescing operator like this:  `NSLog("%@", (self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray) ?? "")`

Comment: `(self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)?[0]` is going to return an optional with the first element of array associated with key "R".  Unless that is an array of arrays you can't call `.count` on that element, and even if you could you have to unwrap it first.

Comment: Simpler approach is   

  if let count =  array?.count{
         return count
        }

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you'll want to return `0` if there's nothing in the array. In that case, try the [Nil Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_124):

```
return (self.jsonObj?["R"] as? NSArray)?.count ?? 0;
```

***Edit:** As @vacawama's answer points out, it should be `self.jsonObj?["R"]` instead of `self.jsonObj["R"]!` in case `self.jsonObj` is `nil`.*

Comment: I get `unexpedly found nil`

Comment: `return (self.jsonObj?["R"]! as? NSArray)?.count ?? 0;` works

Comment: Remember that `!` should be pronounced "I swear on my program's life." So you have to be absolutely certain here that if `jsonObj` exists, it's impossible for the `R` value to be missing (and it's very hard to guarantee that for JSON, since you usually get that from outside your program). @vacawama's solution avoids crashing in that case.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `self.jsonObj` is `NSDictionary?` or `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?`

```
return self.jsonObj?["R"]?.count ?? 0
```

Comment: I don't believe this will compile, since there is no `count` on `AnyObject`.

Comment: @RobNapier "You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property without casting to a more specific class type. " from [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense since `AnyObject` basically translates to `id`. That does mean if this element is something, but not an `NSArray`, it'll crash, right?

Comment: @RobNapier yes. and you can use `.count?` which return `nil` if is called on something does not implement `count`